# get the attachement files from REST API when using select(I need other fields not just attachments)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest

I'm trying to get attachment plus other fields like title, created etc.

When I use the below code

```
var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('News')/items?$select=Title,Created,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles";
```

I cant seem to get the attachments like so

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
    alert(data.d.results[i].AttachmentFiles)
}
```

But then if I use

```
var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('News')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles";
```

Its all good.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help (the whole script):

[https://afrait.com/blog/get-attachment-url-from-list-item-en](https://afrait.com/blog/get-attachment-url-from-list-item-en/)

Attachment is an Object. So get the whole object like this:

> var attachmentUrl = item.AttachmentFiles.results[0]

And then you could do this to get the file name:

> alert(attachmentUrl.FileName);

or save it to a variable of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

`data.d.results[i].AttachmentFiles` is a deferred property that gives you a `uri`. So if you want to get all attachment files, then you have to send another request in that `uri`. You can not get attachments and other fields at the same time in this way.

**Example**

I send a `GET` request to the following url and get following response.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your List Name')/items?$select=ID,Title,AttachmentFiles
```

**Response**

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "9b9428e5-efca-425f-b46f-6082bcc11675",
          "uri": "https://siteUrl/_api/Web/Lists(guid'e4dff311-aeb8-4ec5-9f39-a1d58e2cceb4')/Items(1)",
          "etag": "\"3\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.Induction_x0020_AcknowledgementListItem"
        },
        "AttachmentFiles": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://siteUrl/_api/Web/Lists(guid'e4dff311-aeb8-4ec5-9f39-a1d58e2cceb4')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles"
          }
        },
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "daaa",
        "ID": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I send another request to `d.results[i].AttachmentFiles.__deferred.uri` for getting all attachments.

To get attachments and other fields at the same time, just send a `GET` request to the following URL.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your list name')/items?$select=Title,ID,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

`d.results[i].AttachmentFiles.results` will contain all attachments under a specific list item.